# Copy and Pasting Web page Content into an Office Application.

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I want take information from any website and paste it into Libre Office (text and images).

Firstly, I want record the name/URL, description and some basic information from each website.

Afterwards, my intention is to copy/paste the web-page content into LibreOffice in order to analyze it.

Can Libre Office do this and is it my best option? if not can you recommend a tool which is available for 12.04?

Comment: Please clarify your question with more details. You want data but in Joshua Siret's answer you said something about image. What is meant by "pictures with text" as per your comment. Also how you will get other details? From which website you want the ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use **Nixnote** to do what your trying to achieve not Libre Office.

If your question is **“how can you do this in Libre Office”** then ignore my answer.  My answer is just an alternative that works best for me and many others.  I do a lot of research and need to organize and review web pages (and all their content) regularly.

**Nixnote (formerly Nevernote)** is an open source clone of **Evernote.**

Evernote makes it easy to remember things big and small from your everyday life using your computer, phone, tablet and importantly for you the web.
For this solution you must use the Evernote (clipper) extension for Mozilla Firefox. (Available in FireFox Add-ons)

**Method**

When you browse the internet using Firefox and you come across a website that you want to keep for review (text and Pictures), the EverNote clipper will allow you to this.

When you install NixNote on Ubuntu desktop you can set it up to automatically synchronize with your Evernote note book.  The result will be that all your websites that you want to review will be in the NixNote desktop software.

You can get NixNote [**here**](https://launchpad.net/~vincent-c/+archive/nevernote)

For more information on EverNote [**click here**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evernote)

Answer (score 0):

I would copy and paste the data into a .txt document and import the text document into libre office.

Comment: But, you forget picture. How can I handle lots of pictures with text ?

Comment: The text document will ignore the pictures? I think you need to make the question clearer.